# Possible comic based on [always-friday-in-iceland]?

Tags: discussion, fun

I recently came across [a webcomic](http://www.lefthandedtoons.com/765/) which was titled "Fridaynosaur goes traveling" and the last place he visited(apparently) was Iceland. I believe I recall a programmer-ish comic or two for that webcomic but I can't remember for sure. What do you think? Are the Meta-Memes already becoming mainstream?

Answer (score 2):

Given that this comic is hardly mainstream, I'd have to say no, our memes are not going mainstream.